# AWS monthly billing for dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am going to set up a DynamoDB on aws, and their pricing is about .3$/GB a month. If i store 500 GB for an hour, do some work on it, then remove 200GB after an hour. Do i have to pay for the 500 GB used for the whole month or, 500 GB for the hour it was on the DB ?

Comment: You should check on what interval they bill you. For example EC2 instances bill per hour

Comment: it states per month interval, so i guess it is probably 500GB billed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: it's billed hourly or thereabouts.

[Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/) says

- First 25 GB stored per month is free
- $0.285 per GB-month thereafter

This means 1GB for 1 month costs $0.285. It also means 0.5GB for a month or 1GB for half a month is charged at half that. If you put in a lot of data, use it for a short time, then remove it, you're billed for the time it's stored - I guess at the hour or day level.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

with dynamodb you should worry about write cost than storage cost.

If importing of 500gb data requires you to write 5 milllion records with average record size of 1kb,  costs you 750$

It will cost you same again for deleting.

so be careful with dynamodb :)

Comment: Thanks for this warning. Do you recommend only storing spark processed data in dynamo and keep big data in s3 bucket ?

Comment: again it depends on data size you are storing.
you can store summary data in a s3 object and use s3 select for your queries. price is totally negligible.